# How can I make CPLEX understand which specific part of the tuple I am referring to?

Tags: tuples, cplex

I have this tuple:

```
tuple copie_macchine {

   int macchina;
   int copia1;
   int copia2;
   int copia3; 

 }

{copie_macchine} copie = ...;
```

For example:

```
 copie = {<3,3,4,0>,
 <6,7,8,9>,
 <8,11,12,0>,
 <9,13,14,0>,
 <10,15,16,0>,
 <20,26,27,28>};
```

and I have this part of code:

```
forall (j in J)
    
    forall (m in M )
                   
           forall (i1 in I)
    
              forall (c in copie : c.copia3 !=0 && m == c.copia1 || m == c.copia2 || m == c.copia3)
 
                    {
                      
                      sum (m in M) y[i1][j][m] == 1;   
                                               
                    }
```

How can I make CPLEX understand that for example c.macchina = 3 then refers to c.copia1 = 3, c.copia2 = 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use arrays within the tuple set:

.mod

```
tuple copie_macchine {

   key int macchina;
   int copia1;
   int copia2;
   int copia3; 

 }

{copie_macchine} copie = ...;

tuple copie_macchine2
{

   key int macchina;
   int copies[1..3];

 }
 
 range r=1..3;
 int ar[r];
 
 copie_macchine2 copie2[i in copie]=<i.macchina,ar>;
 
 execute
 {
   copie2;
 }
 
 
 execute
 {
   for(var i in copie)
   {
     copie2[i].copies[1]=i.copia1;
     copie2[i].copies[2]=i.copia2;
     copie2[i].copies[3]=i.copia3;
   }
 }
```

.dat

```
copie = {<3,3,4,0>,
 <6,7,8,9>,
 <8,11,12,0>,
 <9,13,14,0>,
 <10,15,16,0>,
 <20,26,27,28>};
```